# Newbie Lucene Problem with c# demo "The Type or Namespace 'StandardAnalyzer' could not be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lucene.net

I'm trying to get the basic demo of Lucene.net (4.8.0-beta00012) to run.

http://lucenenet.apache.org/#quick-start

I've created a new Forms App.

Run `Install-Package Lucene.Net -Pre` and it's downloaded the nuget package.

Copied and pasted all the demo sections: *Create an index and define a text analyzer*, *Add to the index*, *Construct a query*, and *Fetch the results*.

Visual Studio popped up a load of missing assembly references so I clicked 'Potential Fixes' and let it add the using statements at the start.

```
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using Lucene.Net.Util;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Lucene_CS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensures index backwards compatibility
            var AppLuceneVersion = LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48;

            var indexLocation = @"C:\Index";
            var dir = FSDirectory.Open(indexLocation);

            //create an analyzer to process the text
            var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(AppLuceneVersion);

            //create an index writer
            var indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(AppLuceneVersion, analyzer);
            var writer = new IndexWriter(dir, indexConfig);


            var source = new
            {
                Name = "Kermit the Frog",
                FavoritePhrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            };
            Document doc = new Document
            {

                new StringField("name",
                    source.Name,
                    Field.Store.YES),
                new TextField("favoritePhrase",
                    source.FavoritePhrase,
                    Field.Store.YES)
            };

            writer.AddDocument(doc);
            writer.Flush(triggerMerge: false, applyAllDeletes: false);


            // search with a phrase
            var phrase = new MultiPhraseQuery
            {
                new Term("favoritePhrase", "brown"),
                new Term("favoritePhrase", "fox")
            };

            // re-use the writer to get real-time updates
            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader(applyAllDeletes: true));
            var hits = searcher.Search(phrase, 20 /* top 20 */).ScoreDocs;
            foreach (var hit in hits)
            {
                var foundDoc = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
                hit.Score.Dump("Score");
                foundDoc.Get("name").Dump("Name");
                foundDoc.Get("favoritePhrase").Dump("Favorite Phrase");
            }




        }
    }
}
```

Now I am left with a couple that won't resolve:

```
   var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(AppLuceneVersion);
```

[image]

And .Dump

```
  hit.Score.Dump("Score");
  foundDoc.Get("name").Dump("Name");
  foundDoc.Get("favoritePhrase").Dump("Favorite Phrase");
```

[image]

How would I go about debugging this to determine how to specify the references correctly?

UPDATE WITH `namespace Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StandardAnalyzer` is located in namespace `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard`.

I don't have an answer for you with regard to `.Dump` exactly.
hit.Score is a float, so `hit.Score.Dump("Score");`  is a bit hard for me to imagine.  I did a search of the lucene net repository for the word Dump and there are only 20 occurrences.  https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/search?p=1&q=Dump

One of them is the code tutorial example you are citing.  But none of the other occurrences appear to be the implementation of that Dump method.  So I'm gonna guess that the .Dump is no longer a valid method for the uses cited.

I'd recommend changing

```
foreach (var hit in hits)
            {
                var foundDoc = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
                hit.Score.Dump("Score");
                foundDoc.Get("name").Dump("Name");
                foundDoc.Get("favoritePhrase").Dump("Favorite Phrase");
            }
```

to

```
foreach (var hit in hits)
            {
                var foundDoc = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
                var score = hit.Score;
                var name = foundDoc.Get("name");
                var favoritePhrase = foundDoc.Get("favoritePhrase");
            }
```

That will probably work for you and allow you to inspect the fields retrieved via the debugger.

I might add that while the info on Lucene.Net can seem a bit limiting for a beginner, the system is amazing and crazy powerful.  I say that to encourage you as you are learning it because it's well worth learning.  I love it.

**Update**
Just as @bendecko said in the comment below, you need to install the package `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common` from NuGet.  Sorry I didn't specify that when providing the namespace.

Comment: Thank you.  `Still getting "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Standard' does not exist in the namespace 'Lucene.Net.Analysis' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Lucene CS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Projects\Lucene\Lucene CS\Lucene CS\Form1.cs 6 Active"`

Comment: @bendecko: you need to install the package `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common` from NuGet.

Comment: I have updated the [quick start guide](http://lucenenet.apache.org/#quick-start) to use `Console.WriteLine` instead of `Dump` (which is apparently a `LinqPad` extension method).